# rewrite url using htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

How can I change url in this way using htaccess:

http://example.com/page.php?go=**something**.php

should be redirected to:

http://example.com/**something**

If the get parameter name is different than 'go' leave as it is...

Answer (score 2):

This should do:

```
# Assuming that "RewriteEngine On" has already been called
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*&)?go=([a-z]+)\.php(&.*)?$
RewriteRule page.php %2?
```

What happens here? First, RewriteCond matches a query string that contains the `go=something.php`, where "something" is captured by `([a-z]+)`. Then the RewriteRule uses the second capture group's contents from RewriteCond, containing "something.php". The question mark at the end gets rid of the original query string.

Note: if you want to preserve the rest of the query string excluding `go=...` parameter, things get a bit more complicated.

See the docs in http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html for more info.

Answer (score 1):

something like this (google around for the correct syntax)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^page.php?go=login.php /login [L]
```

Comment: The downside of using this, `page.php?something&go=login.php` doesn't work, and it's still valid on `page.php?go=login.phpjunk`

Comment: google around for correct syntax and how to get around those problems.
e.g. add $ after login.php to prevent login.phpjunk from triggering